# Avoid N+1 queries for accessing parent's parent. that is grandparent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The model hirerachy struture is City HAS_MANY Airport, Airport HAS_MANY Flight

How could I avoid N+1 query in this hirerachy structure.

I can fix the N+1 query for airport by

```
@flights = Flight.includes(:to_airport, :from_airport, :airline).all
```

But there's still N+1 query for accessing city

## API, jbuilder

```
json.array!(@flights) do |flight|
  json.from_airport flight.from
  json.to_airport flight.to
  json.from_city flight.from_airport.city.name
  json.to_city flight.to_airport.city.name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, perhaps you could load the nested association too?

```
Flight.includes(to_airport: :city, :airline)
```

Comment: I don't know I can use it that way, let me try it. thanks~

Comment: mmm. oddly includes doesn't generate the sql, thought it did. I just tried with .eager_load with the same hash syntax and it generates a proper join. Perhaps you can try that?

Comment: `    @flights = Flight.includes(:airline, :to_airport => :city, :from_airport => :city ).all
` this works for me.

Comment: That seems like the old syntax. you could try to_airport: [:city] but both should work mm.